# How to download file from http server that requires a referral before allowing the download?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I usually download file using following code:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("url of the file","filepath to save the file")
```

But recently I encountered a site that only allow file download if you click it from its site and not via direct downloading from vb.net code.

My question is: How to download file from http server that requires a referral before allowing the download?

Comment: Why did you flag this as vb.net and c#? Your code seems to be VB.NET

Comment: @Icarus: I can use code converter to convert to VB.NET

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the Referer header manually:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Referer","http://whatever.com");
wc.DownloadFile("url of the file","filepath to save the file");
```